# UnsatisfiedLinkError while running tomcat 8

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, intellij-idea, tomcat8

When I run an app from tomcat, I keep getting an exception from tomcat

> 01-Sep-2014 02:33:28.377 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
>   01-Sep-2014 02:33:28.377 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8443"]
>   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.tomcat.jni.SSLExt.setNPN(J[BI)I
>       at org.apache.tomcat.jni.SSLExt.setNPN(Native Method)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.jni.SSLExt.setNPN(SSLExt.java:126)
>       at org.apache.coyote.spdy.SpdyAprNpnHandler.init(SpdyAprNpnHandler.java:76)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol.start(Http11AprProtocol.java:211)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:986)

I have tomcat 8.0.11 with APR.
I have changed Connector settings for server.xml so that it uses APR now:

```
    <Connector port="8443"
               maxThreads="150"
               scheme="https"
               secure="true"
               SSLEnabled="true"
               protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"
               sslProtocol="TLS"
               npnHandler="org.apache.coyote.spdy.SpdyAprNpnHandler"
               SSLCertificateFile="somecertificate.cer"
               SSLCertificateKeyFile="somekey.key"/>
```

tomcat lib directory has openssl.exe (v. 1.0.1h) and tcnative-1.dll (v. 1.1.31)
tomcat, openssl and tcnative are all x64. I am using jdk 1.7

I tried to add tomcat lib folder to the path, but it didn't change a thing, I am still getting this exception.

I run my app from within intellij IDEA ultimate

Could anyone please point me where to look for a solution?

Comment: 1, Is the JDK you are using 64-bit? 2, Use Dependency Walker to make sure you have all dependencies in Path http://www.dependencywalker.com.

Comment: @longhua 1. Yes, jdk is also x64. Application runs fine on tomcat 8.0 without SpdyApnHandler. 2. These are first 3 lines from log on load:

org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.init Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.1.31 using APR version 1.4.8.

org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.init APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].

org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized (OpenSSL 1.0.1h 5 Jun 2014)

I.e. native library was loaded properly.

Comment: does it work well without IDEA? Just deploy your application to tomcat directly.

Comment: @longhua Yeah, it's the same unfortunately. Looks like intellij doesn't do anything fancy.

Comment: So tomcat works well if it isn't started by IntelliJ. In this case, maybe you can check your IntelliJ's environment. Or add the path to the tc-native libraries, apr and OpenSSL to PATH  http://tomcat.apache.org/native-doc/.

Comment: @longhua No, tomcat works the same. It gives same exception. I am sorry if you have being confused by my former response. Also, I have stated that openssl is in the path in my original question.

Comment: OK, in this case, you need to use Dependency Walker to make sure you have added all required libraries to Path. As I remember, you need ssleay32.dll and libeay32.dll for OpenSSL.

Comment: @longhua OpenSSL works and is in the path. I ran openssl from tomcat lib and got openssl prompt. I typed `version` and got `OpenSSL 1.0.1h 5 Jun 2014`

Comment: No, you need to check you have add those dynamic libraries of OpenSSL to Path. openssl.exe maybe static compiled.

Comment: @longhua Ah! Alright, I do not have these in lib. Will try and report in a second

Comment: @longhua I took dynamic version of openssl. Same version, 1.0.1h, x64 with libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll and put them in the path. Verified that openssl works. But tomcat still throws that exception.

It looks like something wrong with a method. I.e. it can't find method from the lib. How can I verify it?

Comment: I am not sure what did you mean by "something wrong with a method". Have you tried Dependency Walker to check apr dll and tcnative dll?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60365/discussion-between-longhua-and-oddy).